# Get five nearest Geolocation names from my position using lat, long

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geolocation

I am trying to display the information depending on user position. So, here I want to display five nearest locations (names) to that user based on his position.

How can I do that, using JavaScript. Help me.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript gives you an ability to get geolocation of the user. That's all.

[Geolocation WebAPI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation)

If you want to get some places near your geolocation, you need to use any geo service API such as google maps, or yandex maps and others.

I suggest you to look at this repo: https://github.com/googlemaps/js-store-locator

Additionally, you can see example of what you want here:
https://googlemaps.github.io/js-store-locator/examples/places.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [Google Maps Places API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-search):

- get the list of places nearby your location
- sort them by distance
- get 5 nearest places
- show them in the list under the map
- you need to load two Google Maps libraries: Places and Geometry
- and don't forget to get your google maps api key

Here is the code and working fiddle [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/svitch/mdha6s7L/23/):

HTML:

```
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="places"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places,geometry&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

CSS:

```
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
 * element that contains the map. */
#map {
  height: calc(100% - 200px);
}
/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#places {
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 10px 15px;
}
```

Javascript:

```
// This example requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
// parameter when you first load the API. For example:
// <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">

var map;
var infowindow;
var currentLat = -33.867;
var currentLng = 151.195;
var list = document.getElementById('places');

function initMap() {
  var currentPoint = {lat: currentLat, lng: currentLng};
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: currentPoint,
    zoom: 15
  });

  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  service.nearbySearch({
    location: currentPoint,
    radius: 500,
    type: ['store']
  }, callback);
}

function callback(results, status) {
  if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    var nearestPlaces = getnearestPlaces(results, 5);
    for (var i = 0; i < nearestPlaces.length; i++) {
      listPlaces(nearestPlaces[i]);
    }
  }
}

function getnearestPlaces(places, numberOfResults) {
    var closest = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < places.length; i++) {
        var fromPoint = new google.maps.LatLng(currentLat, currentLng);
        var toPoint = new google.maps.LatLng(places[i].geometry.location.lat, places[i].geometry.location.lng);
        places[i].distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(fromPoint, toPoint);
        closest.push(places[i]);
    }
    closest.sort(sortByDist);
    return closest.splice(0,numberOfResults);
}

function sortByDist(a, b) {
    return (a.distance - b.distance)
}

function listPlaces(place) {
  console.log(place);
  list.innerHTML += '<p>' + place.name + '</p>';
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/svitch/mdha6s7L/23/)

Comment: thanks for reply. I don't want to mark them in map. I want to display location names below the map.